# i got this error: Warning:Gradle version 2.10 is required

Tags: android

I got this weird error.

> Warning:Gradle version 2.10 is required. 
>           Current version is 2.8. 
>           If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in
>   D:\RaymondAndroidProjects\testPaypal\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties
>   to gradle-2.10-all.zip

Comment: Are you using uptodate Android Studio. If not update it and update the support Libraries as well

Comment: what so weird about that? just change your gradle version in `gradle-wrapper.properties` in your project

Comment: That's a pity. And what you want from us? You forgot to tell that.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Gradle Version 2.10 is required." Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814368/gradle-version-2-10-is-required-error)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to `File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle`.
 Choose `Use default gradle wrapper`

Answer (score 10):

last time started a new project i also got this problem, solved by change my Project build.gradle dependencies classpath from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
```

Answer (score 8):

**set Use default gradle wrapper and edit Project\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties files field distributionUrl like this**

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

[image]

[image]