# android studio stuck on Gradle sync started . GCM google cloud messaging sync with its dependencies and plugins

Tags: android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

I try to use GCM on my app but when I start step by step as the steps on

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

I have added the dependencies and plugins as required
than I press sync on android studio
but until now it take more than one and half hour form 
Gradle sync started

Gradle:Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/.............

is it normal or some error happened 
if it is ok how long it will take ?
if it is not normal what should I do ?

now it  stopped and wa

```
Warning:Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.4. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in D:\android\STRONTAXI\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749299/gradle-version-2-2-is-required-current-version-is-2-10 / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34805369/i-got-this-error-warninggradle-version-2-10-is-required

Answer (score 0):

my android studio rework fine just
when I

1. delete the Gradle
2. from the Build menu I choose rebuild project